# Why this short if doesnt work ? message.startsWith("www.")? JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, "Url is") :

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, unary-operator

I would like to fix this error, why this short if is not correct. A normal `if()` than another if does work for me.

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {        
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {      
       String message = text.getText();

       message.startsWith("www.")? 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, "Url is") : 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, "Message");
```

More about this issue also: Why "else if" does work for me ? And how to change this

[image]

symbol in the JFrame window, to alert, exclamation mark (!), warning symbols?
Thanks,
Ea.

Comment: Please post a code that we can test effectively. See [mcve]. Also, ask only one question per post.

Comment: You can't use a unary operator like this; it is mainly for returning a value based on a boolean expression.  Try changing it to `if (message.startsWith("www.")) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, "Url is") } else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, "Message");}`

Comment: Because ternary `... ? ... : ...` is _not_ a "short if" statement, but an expression (e.g. to be used in an assignment, or for a parameter)

Comment: @SteveSmith I use 3 if() for this function there in no else, it's important.

Comment: In this case, you could make it shorter (and working) by using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, message.startsWith("www.") ? "Url is" : "message");`

Comment: You can learn a lot by reading [the JOptionPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).  In this case, you want the [showMessageDialog method that takes a message type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int)).